# A star algorithm with ability to remove N obstacle(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x, a-star, maze

To keep my coding sharp I started with some typical puzzles. I found an implementation of the A* algorithm. The next step would be to adapt it so N obstacles can be removed to find the optimal path. If a maze is represented as seen below where 1's represent the obstacles:

```
[[0, 1, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 1, 1, 0], 
 [1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

The A* implementation:
import heapq

```
class Cell:
    def __init__(self,x,y,passable):
        self.passable = passable
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.g = 0
        self.h = 0
        self.f = 0
        self.parent = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Cell((%s, %s), %s)' % (self.x, self.y, self.passable) 

class Maze:
    def __init__(self,maze_map):
        self.maze_map = maze_map
        self.cells = []
        self.maze_height = None
        self.maze_width = None
        self.cells_to_visit = []
        heapq.heapify(self.cells_to_visit)
        self.cells_visited = set()

    def initialize_cells(self):
        self.maze_height = len(self.maze_map)
        self.maze_width = len(self.maze_map[0])
        door_start = (0,0)
        door_end = (self.maze_height-1,self.maze_width-1)

        for h in range(self.maze_height):
            for w in range(self.maze_width):
                if self.maze_map[h][w] == 0:
                    passable = True
                else:
                    passable = False
                self.cells.append(Cell(w,h,passable))

        self.start = self.get_cell(*door_start)
        self.end = self.get_cell(*door_end)

    def calculate_heuristic(self,cell):
        cost = 10
        return cost * (abs(cell.x - self.end.x) + abs(cell.y - self.end.y))

    def get_cell(self, x, y):
        return self.cells[x * self.maze_height + y]

    def get_path(self):
        cell = self.end
        path = [(cell.x, cell.y)]
        while cell.parent is not self.start:
            cell = cell.parent
            path.append((cell.x, cell.y))

        path.append((self.start.x, self.start.y))
        path.reverse()
        return path

    def update_cell(self, adj, cell):
        adj.g = cell.g + 10
        adj.h = self.calculate_heuristic(adj)
        adj.parent = cell
        adj.f = adj.h + adj.g

    def get_adjacent_cells(self,cell):
        cells = []
        if cell.x < self.maze_width-1:
            cells.append(self.get_cell(cell.x+1, cell.y))
        if cell.y > 0:
            cells.append(self.get_cell(cell.x, cell.y-1))
        if cell.x > 0:
            cells.append(self.get_cell(cell.x-1, cell.y))
        if cell.y < self.maze_width-1:
            cells.append(self.get_cell(cell.x, cell.y+1))
        return cells

    def solve(self):
        heapq.heappush(self.cells_to_visit, self.start)
        while len(self.cells_to_visit):            
            cell = heapq.heappop(self.cells_to_visit)
            self.cells_visited.add(cell)

            if cell is self.end:
                return self.get_path()

            adj_cells = self.get_adjacent_cells(cell)
            for adj_cell in adj_cells:
                if adj_cell not in self.cells_visited:
                    if (adj_cell.f, adj_cell) in self.cells_to_visit:
                        if adj_cell.g > cell.g + 10:
                            self.update_cell(adj_cell, cell)
                    else:
                        self.update_cell(adj_cell, cell)
                        heapq.heappush(self.cells_to_visit, adj_cell)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    m = [[0, 1, 1, 0], 
         [0, 0, 1, 0], 
         [1, 1, 1, 0], 
         [1, 0, 1, 0]]

    N = 1 #allowed to remove 1 obstacle
    maze = Maze(map,N)
    maze.initialize_cells()
    maze.solve()

    m = [[0, 1, 1, 0], 
         [0, 0, 1, 0], 
         [1, 1, 1, 1], 
          [1, 0, 1, 0]]

    N = 2 #allowed to remove 2 obstacles
    maze = Maze(map,N)
    maze.initialize_cells()
    maze.solve()
```

Starting with possibility of removing one obstacle, how easy to make it generalisable to N? Also, how should one implement such thing?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would like say that if you have an information about the problem such that "there are few obstacles that need to be removed" (meaning that obstacles are sparse) an algorithm that works by only considering obstacles may going to be faster. But I will give a general solution (**I turned problem into a pathfinding problem**) and some advices.

1- There is a trick used in games (well, at least I know this from the games). Remember that there are costs in A* algorithm. For example in games if you want a water path to be more costly than a ground path, you increase "g" value in water areas more compared to ground areas. The trick is using this cost feature cleverly. In some games when you try to move a character from point A to point B and there is not an empty path between the points, the character doesn't just stand there but walks to point B as much as it can. This is done by **instead of completely discarding unpassable areas, you assign them a very high cost**. Result of this is character starts to walk to the thinnest obstacle between two points instead of standing doing nothing. If we adopt this idea to your problem, problem basically turns into "find path with least amount of 1s". (Lines 46, 106 and 139 in my code)

2- I usually don't do things in python so I wrap heap operations in a PriorityQueue class (I took this class code from somewhere else, not sure where). But I think it is easier to manage things this way, also main A* body looks clear.

3- You don't need to write separate if statement for different directions (right, up, left, down). Yes, there is an argument that it is faster but if you really need that amount of speed you might as well not use python. (line 92-93, and line 122-124 to see usage)

4- I used manhattan distance as heuristic assuming only 4 cardinal directions are allowed for movement, if diagonal moves are allowed it should be changed to euclidian distance and 4 other directions need to be considered.

```
import time
import random


#  use whichever data structure you like
import heapq


class Node():

    #  maybe calculate h value inside function instead of taking as arg
    def __init__(self, parent_node, row, col, g, h):
        self.parent_node = parent_node
        self.row = row
        self.col = col
        self.g = g
        self.h = h

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.g + self.h < other.g + other.h




class PriorityQueue: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.elements = []

    def empty(self):
        return len(self.elements) == 0

    def put(self, item, priority):
        heapq.heappush(self.elements, (priority, item))

    def get(self):
        return heapq.heappop(self.elements)[1]


class Maze:
    def __init__(self, maze_map):
        self.maze_map = maze_map
        self.maze_height = len(self.maze_map)
        self.maze_width = len(self.maze_map[0])

        #  this number must be large enough compared to your maze size
        self.OBSTACLE_COST = 1000


    def print_maze(self):
        for row in self.maze_map:
            for col in row:
                print(col, end='')
            print("")


    def calculate_h(self, row, col):
        #  lets use manhattan distance, since we do not go diagonally
        #convert to euclidian if diagonal movement is allowed
        return abs(row - end_row) + abs(col - end_col)

    def solve(self, start_row, start_col, goal_row, goal_col):
        self.start_row = start_row
        self.start_col = start_col
        self.end_row = end_row
        self.end_col = end_col


        #  initialize result variables
        found_path = []
        found_path_cost = 0



        #  create root A* node
        h_initial = self.calculate_h(start_row, start_col)
        s0 = Node(None, start_row, start_col, 0, h_initial)


        #  create our priority queue and put root node in it
        Q = PriorityQueue()
        Q.put(s0, s0.h+0)


        #  keep visited/closed set, (so we are performing graph search) 
        closed_set = {}


        #  these will be useful
        #these numbers correspond to RIGHT,UP,LEFT,DOWN respectively
        #for right change in y=0 and change in x = 1
        #...
        dy = [0, -1, 0, 1]
        dx = [1, 0, -1, 0]
        while (not Q.empty()):
            #  pop a node from the priority queue
            s = Q.get()

            if (s.row == self.end_row and s.col == self.end_col):
                #  solved, obtain the path by following parents of nodes
                current_node = s
                while current_node.parent_node != None:
                    found_path.append(current_node)
                    if (self.maze_map[current_node.row][current_node.col] == 0):
                        found_path_cost += 1
                    else:
                        found_path_cost += self.OBSTACLE_COST

                    current_node = current_node.parent_node

                found_path.reverse()
                break


            #  expand node s
            #  here I converted current position into a tuple of
            #row and col, then converted this tuple to a string
            #so it can be used as a dictionary key
            closed_set[str((s.row, s.col))] = 1


            #  continue searching, create child nodes of current node
            s_row = s.row
            s_col = s.col
            for d in range(4): #letter "d" represent direction
                #letter "n" represent neighbour
                n_row = s.row + dy[d]
                n_col = s.col + dx[d]

                #  check if neighbour node is in maze bounds
                if (n_row >= 0 and n_row < self.maze_height and
                    n_col >= 0 and n_col < self.maze_width):

                    #  if this neighbour is already visited (already in
                    #closed list) discard it
                    if (str((n_row, n_col)) in closed_set):
                        continue

                    #  calculate new g and h value for the child node
                    new_g = s.g+1 if (self.maze_map[n_row][n_col] == 0) else s.g+self.OBSTACLE_COST
                    new_heuristic = self.calculate_h(n_row, n_col)


                    #  create new child node and add it to the priority queue

                    new_s = Node(s, n_row, n_col, new_g, new_heuristic)
                    Q.put(new_s, new_s.g + new_s.h)


        print("Number of obstacles along the path:", int(found_path_cost/self.OBSTACLE_COST))
        print("Found path manhattan dist:", len(found_path))
        return found_path, found_path_cost

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #
    #  MAZE 1
    #
    print("\n MAZE 1\n")
    m = [[0, 1, 1, 0], 
         [0, 0, 1, 0], 
         [1, 1, 1, 0], 
         [1, 0, 1, 0]]
    maze = Maze(m)
    maze.print_maze()

    start_row = 0
    start_col = 0
    end_row = len(m)-1
    end_col = len(m[0])-1
    maze.solve(start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col)


    #
    #  MAZE 2
    #
    print("\n MAZE 2\n")
    m = [[0, 1, 1, 0], 
         [0, 0, 1, 0], 
         [1, 1, 1, 1], 
          [1, 0, 1, 0]]
    maze = Maze(m)
    maze.print_maze()

    start_row = 0
    start_col = 0
    end_row = len(m)-1
    end_col = len(m[0])-1
    maze.solve(start_row, start_col, end_row, end_col)
```

Outputs:

```
 MAZE 1

0110
0010
1110
1010
Number of obstacles along the path: 1
Found path manhattan dist: 6

 MAZE 2

0110
0010
1111
1010
Number of obstacles along the path: 2
Found path manhattan dist: 6
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. It indeed works quite nicely, I still have to get a closer look to your implementation. However, for bigger mazes I found the solution to be suboptimal i.e. the manhattan distance is larger than the optimal distance.
An example of such a maze: [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
Can you please explain how this could be?

Comment: @user3488736 Because there is already a clear path from start to goal. No obstacles need to be removed and algorithm finds that way. If you want to, you can change "cost" of removing an obstacle to for example 5, so performing 5 steps in empty squares would be equal to stepping over an obstacle etc.